# Display a link only if no link is present using ColdFusion?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8

So the announcement functionality on our site displays a "read more" link by default using the following code (in part):

```
<cfif announcement.recordCount gt 0>
<cfloop query="announcement">
<cfoutput>
<td colspan="2"><span class="left">#teaser_text# <a href="/announcements/?id=#id#" title="Read more...">Read more &raquo;</a>

</cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```

(Note, there is a cfquery statement prior to that, which I excluded for brevity in the code)

What I'm trying to do here is get the "Read More" link to show after the #teaser_text# only if no link is contained within #teaser_text#, so that I can manually add links in if needed and remove the automatically generated link.

Any thoughts on a cfif statement that would do this?

Thanks.

EDIT: To clarify, I want to remove "Read more" if ANY link is found within teaser_text.

Comment: Do you want to remove the read more link if _any_ link is found within teaser_text, or only remove it if a link to `/announcements/?id=#id#` exists?

Comment: BTW, if there is nothing between the cfif/cfloop in your original code (and nothing after the `</cfloop>` and `</cfif>`, you don't need the cfif at all - a cfloop for a zero row query will just skip. You can also merge the cfloop and cfoutput to look like `<cfoutput query="announcement">` too.

Comment: Updated to clarify - I want to remove "Read more" if any URL is found within teaser_text.

Comment: Well that doesn't sound the best idea, but I've updated my answer to so it basically looks for `<a href=` and doesn't check for /announce...etc

Comment: Does it not sound like a good idea from a programming perspective, or because I didn't fully explain my reasoning? Because for many announcements we post, the read more link is useless, where a regular link to one of our other pages is more helpful.

Comment: It's probably irrelevant if your teaser text links to your other pages (or to entirely different websites). If an announcement has more to read, you should show the read more link, if it doesn't, don't show it. i.e. what you most likely want is `<cfif teaser_text NEQ body_text> [read more] </cfif>`

Answer (score 5):

To only show the read more link if no hyperlink is found within teaser_text, this check is likely to be good enough:

```
<cfif NOT refindNoCase('<a\s[^>]*?\bhref\s*=',teaser_text) >
    <a href="/announcements/?id=#id#" title="Read more...">Read more &raquo;</a>
</cfif>
```

If you want to check for URLs, not for hyperlinks, you need to get more fancy.

You also need to remember that this is treating teaser_text as *text* (not as HTML), so commenting out a link will not prevent it from being found (if that matters, you need to investigate HTML DOM parsers; and there aren't any for CF so you'd need to look at the Java ones).

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<cfif findnocase('http://', teaser_text) eq 0>
        <a href="/announcements/?id=#id#" title="Read more...">Read more &raquo;</a>    
        </cfif>
```

If you are placing the links in manually just change the first parameter of the findnocase() function [i.e. htp/https] or use a regex to figure out if it is a url [via: refindnocse() ]

-sean

Comment: Except the example link doesn't contain `http://` where as an _external_ link probably would, (and most likely an external link shouldn't exclude the read more from showing), so this would fail in two ways. :/

Comment: Timothy can place whatever he wants as the first parameter & since he's entering links manually, he should be able to maintain it. - not sure what you mean by excluding the "read more" - however, I do agree maybe searching for "href=" would be a better option to maintain internal manual links.

Comment: Searching for `http://` will not detect `<a href="/stuff">` so the read more link would be incorrectly shown. If the text contained `http://google.com` then the link would be excluded. It's still slightly vague if Timothy cares about hyperlinks vs URLs, but checking for a href definitely seems like something that will be more correct at this stage.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do what you want

```
<cfif announcement.recordCount gt 0>
<cfloop query="announcement">
<cfif  findnocase("href",anouncement.teaser_text) >
<a href="/announcements/?id=#announcement.id#"> #anouncement.teaser_text# </a>
<cfelse>
<a href="/announcements/?id=#announcement.id#" >   #anouncement.teaser_text#  Read more </a>
</cfif>
</cfloop>
</cfif>
```

Comment: Why have you wrapped the entire teaser text in a hyperlink, and placed identical text on both sides of the cfif/cfelse? :/